# Asp.net Authentication without identity does not persists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement a login form for my aspnet core 2.0 website.
I'm setting a persistence of 14 days but after 30 minutes the Identity.User.IsAuthenticathed property returns False

My statup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
        });

    var servConfiguration = Configuration.GetSection("ServConfiguration");
    services.Configure<ServConfigurationModel>(servConfiguration);
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
    {
        MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax,
        HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
        Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

my login method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] LoginModel loginData)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            logger.LogWarning("invalid login data username: " + "Username: " + loginData.Username);
            return View();
        }

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginData.Username)
        };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            claims,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            IsPersistent = true,
            AllowRefresh = true
        });
    }
```

my login check

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginCheck()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("user is authenticated");
        }
        else
        {
            logger.LogInformation("user is not authenticated");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

please note: the aspnet cookie has the right expireation, but after 30 minutes if i return in the site the user is not still logged in.

Comment: Can you also add the signature of your login method, and the method where the call to `User.IsAuthenticathed` returns false?

Comment: done, i added  the method where the call to User.IsAuthenticathed returns false

Comment: hmm... It should work. Try to set `ExpireTimeSpan` to 10 seconds just to check that it has an effect.

Comment: Is the cookie present on the second request? Is your site a single node or multiple? Is your site restarting in that time period? These can be related to data protection issues that would prevent the cookie from being read.

Comment: Umm... you *are* using Identity. Where do you think `Claim` comes from?

Comment: as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x#tabpanel_o9XcN0Bk3e_aspnetcore2x

Comment: @Tratcher yes the cookie is still present on second request, the cookie ttl is 14 days, this is a single site no multiple nodes, no the iis application pool is not restarting in the test interval. You gave me a good idea, I will try to set a static Machine Key instead of the default value (autogenerated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem setting a fixed machine key on iis general settings.

The machine key is used for algorithms and keys for encryption, decryption, and validation of forms-authentication data and view-state data, and for out-of-process session state identification.

If the machine key is autogenerated (default) for each restart a new key is generated, then in spite of the session cookie exists it is not still valid because the key has been changed.

[image: IIS Settings - Machine key]